# Get all object pairs into one Array (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, jsx

I have an array like this :

```
const arr = [{name: "some", category: "Cat1"}, {name: "else", category: "Cat2"}, {name: "stuff", category: "Cat2"}]
```

I want to create a new array that only have category without pairs like that :

```
const newArr =[Cat1, Cat2]
```

and then map over it to render into my JSX Element. I try a lot of stuff but nothing worked Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `set object` approach is the best approach. As it is already mentioned here I am going to show the other approaches.

### Using Object:

You could use  `Array.prototype.forEach()` method with `Nullish coalescing operator (??)` to do your job.

```js
const arr = [
  { name: 'some', category: 'Cat1' },
  { name: 'else', category: 'Cat2' },
  { name: 'stuff', category: 'Cat2' },
];
const ret = {};
arr.forEach((x) => {
  ret[x.category] = ret[x.category] ?? x.category;
});
console.log(Object.values(ret));
```

### Using Map Object:

Map object stores key value pairs with the original insertion order. Although object is similar to map object but map object performs better when you need to do a lot of additions and deletions.

```js
const arr = [
  { name: 'some', category: 'Cat1' },
  { name: 'else', category: 'Cat2' },
  { name: 'stuff', category: 'Cat2' },
];
const map = new Map();
const ret = [];
arr.forEach((x) => {
  if (!map.has(x.category)) {
    map.set(x.category, true);
    ret.push(x.category);
  }
});
console.log(ret);
```

### Using Array:

`Array.prototype.includes()` method checks if the array contains the specified element or not and returns true or false based on that.

```js
const arr = [
  { name: 'some', category: 'Cat1' },
  { name: 'else', category: 'Cat2' },
  { name: 'stuff', category: 'Cat2' },
];
const ret = [];
arr.forEach((x) => {
  if (!ret.includes(x.category)) ret.push(x.category);
});
console.log(ret);
```

### Using Reduce Method:

`Array.prototype.reduce()` method runs the given function for each iteration and reduces the array to a single value.

```js
const arr = [
  { name: 'some', category: 'Cat1' },
  { name: 'else', category: 'Cat2' },
  { name: 'stuff', category: 'Cat2' },
];

const ret = Object.values(
  arr.reduce((prev, c) => {
    const p = prev;
    const key = c.category;
    if (!p[key]) p[key] = c.category;
    return p;
  }, {})
);
console.log(ret);
```

Comment: What is the best way between yours and the other answers ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
const arr = [
  {name: "some", category: "Cat1"}, 
  {name: "else", category: "Cat2"}, 
  {name: "stuff", category: "Cat2"}
]

const result = arr.map(a=> a.category);
console.log([...new Set(result)]);
```

Comment: that's perfect !

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something like this:

```js
const arr = [{name: "some", category: "Cat1"}, {name: "else", category: "Cat2"}, {name: "stuff", category: "Cat2"}];

console.log([...new Set(arr.map(x => x.category))]);
```